# Is the fifth column in affix rule optional?

Tags: hunspell

For e.g. this is an example of correct rule.

```
PFX A Y 1
PFX A 0 a .
```

Can I omit the fifth column (dot means any character) and still get the same results? For e.g.

```
PFX A Y 1
PFX A 0 a
```

Comment: I have tested this and it seems that the last column is optional if I am going to use a dot in there. But is this official and documented?